# Spring cache of two Grails applications in the same machine (different Jetty server)

Tags: spring, caching, grails

Hi I have one Grails application, it uses Spring cache. I want to clone it (say APP_A and APP_B) and deploy on separate it as each access different DB and has some different configuration.

Currently I have two copy of Jetty servers (JETTY_A, JETTY_B. different port). I put APP_A in Jetty_A and APP_B in Jetty_B.

I'm not familiar with Spring cache. 
Is this deployment save? I mean, will there be any mix of cache between both? Because both using the same code base. So, the cache will use the same key name.

```
@cacheable("someCache")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpringCache uses EHCache under the covers. The caches are in-process caches and they do not  affect caches running in other processes on the same machine, unless you had explicitly configured distributed caching.

Answer (score 0):

As @KenLiu said in his answer, Spring Cache is strictly in-process when using EHCache as it's cache provider. Since you are working with Grails, however, there are better alternatives that will require only minimal changes.

The [Grails Cache Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cache) is a offers a Spring Cache API-compatible cache abstraction over a number of (plugable) cache providers, including some, like the [Redis provider](http://grails.org/plugin/cache-redis), that allow you to cache between processes (and entire machines) very easily.